# Why my code can't understand time variables for comparing within the if statement?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I wrote a program to run a block of code at a certain time I set, But the problem is that the program can't understand time variables for comparing(there isn't any bug but it's not working the way it should) and it won't stop when the program reaches the limit within if statement, So it keeps printing hours and minutes that I don't want. I would really appreciate it if someone help me.

```
from datetime import time, datetime
while True:
   now = datetime.now()
   end = datetime(2020, 9, 29, 16, 37, 5, 850000)
   now_str = str(now)
   end_str = str(end)
   diff = end - now
   print(diff)
   if now_str == end_str:
       break
```

and rest of the code will be after if statement.

Comment: You can use `datetime.strftime()` to output your date in whatever format you want, with whatever pieces you want, which includes a way that's easy to compare. Alternatively, if you don't want hours and minutes, you could use `datetime.date` instead of `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: You only break if `now` and `end` are _exactly equal_, to the fraction of a second. Shouldn't you just test the `diff` instead of comparing the strings?

Comment: There's also no point converting those `datetime` objects to strings for comparison. You can compare `datetime` objects directly.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, But the problem is that I cant iterate over the direct datetime object in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of comparing the strings you can compare the timestamps itself. As you want to run the code until the end timestamp is reached, use >= for comparison and not ==, as maybe the code is not evaluating the end timestamp at the exact moment and than the equals condition will never be met.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
from datetime import time, datetime
while True:
   now = datetime.now()
   end = datetime(2020, 9, 30, 15, 36, 5, 850000)
   diff = end - now
   print(diff)
   if now >= end:
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [compare datetimes directly](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-compare-two-dates-with-datetime-in-python) using < and >:

```
>>> n1 = datetime.now()
>>> n2 = datetime.now()
>>> n1
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 9, 34, 32, 350522)
>>> n2
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 9, 34, 39, 373229)
>>> n1 < n2
True
```

You should avoid using `==` with `datetime.now()` to end loops, because they are so precise that a microsecond difference might mean you overshoot the planned end time. Use `if now >= end:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other suggestion.

```
from datetime import  datetime
import time

now = datetime.now()
end = datetime(year=2020, month=9, day=30, hour=15, minute=40, second=0, microsecond=850000)
diff = end - now

print("trying to sleep for {} seconds!".format(diff.total_seconds()))

try:
    time.sleep(diff.total_seconds())
except:
    # when the difference "diff" is negative, the sleep() function with raise an exception
    print("Oups, No time to sleep!")
    
print("Run the code here...!")
```

Using a loop to wait for time to end like that is not a very good idea. Since these instructions will repeat executing while trying to use as much of your CPU as is available until the condition is true.
I think you'd better off using `time.sleep ()`. and letting the operating system handle it for you.